# How to read and write a list object into a file

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamreader

I had written a list object to a file like this

```
 private List<string> _cacheFileList=new List<string>(4);
_cacheFileList.Add("Something");
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"cache.bin")) 
                {
                    file.Write(_cacheFileList);
                }
```

Now how could I retrieve whole list object??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `StreamWriter` like that, use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.90).aspx) to serialize your list. Then you can easily retrieve your list back by deserializing. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.90).aspx) has a good example about how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a text file with a single line per list entry, you could try the code below. Of course, you would need error handling and need to ensure that the strings in the list did not contain newlines.

```
// Write
List<string> _listA = new List<string>(4);
_listA.Add("Test");
_listA.Add("Test2");
_listA.Add("Test3");
_listA.Add("Test4");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("test.txt", _listA);

// Read
List<string> _listB = new List<string>(4);
_listB.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just write your list line by line then you can modify your code like this:

```
var cacheFileList = new List<string>(4);
cacheFileList.Add("Something");

using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"cache.bin"))
{
    file.Write(string.Join("\r\n", cacheFileList));
}
```